# Reason of poor performance of ANSI joins in Oracle 9i

Tags: performance, join, syntax, oracle-9i, sql-standard

**Please before flagging as duplicate, read the last paragraphs.**

In an Oracle 9i database this query runs in **0.18 seconds**:

```
select
    count(*)
from 
    dba_synonyms s,dba_objects t
where
    s.TABLE_OWNER = t.OWNER(+) and
    s.TABLE_NAME = t.OBJECT_NAME(+) and
    s.DB_LINK is null and
    t.OWNER is null;
```

...but this one runs in an appalling **120 seconds**!:

```
select
    count(*)
from 
    dba_synonyms s left join dba_objects t 
                   on ( s.TABLE_OWNER = t.OWNER and s.TABLE_NAME = t.OBJECT_NAME ) 
where                   
    s.DB_LINK is null and
    t.OWNER is null
```

Notice the only difference is using propietary Oracle join syntax vs ANSI join syntax.

**This question is not a duplicate** of [this one](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75838/drastic-change-in-query-speed-when-changing-from-oracle-9i-to-ansi-outer-join-sy) because that other question is about a very complex query involving more than 9 tables, and the only answer points out that the queries are very different besides the syntax usage (mainly the order of the tables).

In my case it is a extremelly simple query, a mere join between two relations with no mayor complications of differences, including the order of tables.

- **Is this a bug in Oracle 9i?**
- **What is the cause of such dramatic    difference in performance?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a long time with no answers. I've done some testing.

I ran the same query in 10g and 11g and both versions, the one with ANSI joins and the ones with the WHERE joins run in less than 1 second.

As problems exists only in 9i, the same version the support for ANSI joins where introduced I assume it's a bug in 9i that could or could have not be solved in a patch.

Gladly as I mentioned, from 10g onwards both flavors of joins perform well.